# Would extra mega pixels be worth to upgrade from a 24 MP full frame?

Tags: dslr, full-frame, megapixels

I have heard that extreme high resolution is not always a good thing specially when it comes to low-light performance. On the other hand, since the size of the image gets larger, it may need higher buffer for contentious shooting which slows down the performance for shooting sports. However, I've noticed that both Canon and Nikon have already decided to go on a mega pixel race as the 5D Mark IV has gone to 30 MP and D850 has gone over 45 MP, not to mention Sony that pioneered high mega pixel cameras.

Considering D750 or D5 or 5D Mark III, would it be really worth to upgrade from these cameras to the new high resolution models? Is that extra resolution something very tangible?

On the other hand, if high resolution is a good thing, why the high-end full frames are kept at max 20 MP (D5) of even 12 MP (A7S II) ?

Comment: You're asking multiple questions here, please try and make it one specific question which can be given a specific answer - we can never tell you if something is "worth it" as that's a very individual question based on your own circumstances.

Comment: You haven't really mentioned any real use case. Are you actually facing a (resolution) problem with your current gear? What is it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you needed high MP camera, you would know it, so no, it's not worth it.

> Is that extra resolution something very tangible?

For who? You? Me? Carl Taylor?

> On the other hand, if high resolution is a good thing, why the
>   high-end full frames are kept at max 20 MP (D5) of even 12 MP (A7S II)
>   ?

Because most people don't need high MP. High MP is great when it comes to printing HUGE-sized photos (e.g. an advert on a building), but it comes with its problems too - you need expensive lenses to utilize extra MP, it's more expensive to manufacture, the files are huge and so on.

More stripes doesn't mean more Adidas.

Comment: Personally I don't think an advert on a building needs super high resolution. The viewing distance is huge. Apple's "Shot on iPhone" campaign backs that up.